# Unable to understand how value converted to date format implicitly

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

As I checked my `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `DD-MM-RR`.

Considering mytable with a date column,when I execute the following statement, it throws error "ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format"which is reasonably understandable.

```
insert into mytable values('10'); //Error: reason understandable
```

Then why is following statement valid where clearly the input size is greater than size of default `DATE Format`.

```
insert into mytable values('10AUGUST2016'); //reason not understandable
```

Also here I did not use any `TO_DATE` function, I guess implicit conversion is taking place?

Comment: yes `insert into mytable values('10');`  will throw `ORA-01861:` error as I explained and I understand reason behind it. Do you get any error for `insert into mytable values('10AUGUST2016');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [String-to-Date Conversion Rules](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#sthref478) allow additional formatting rules (without any other modifiers being applied). So:

- `MM` also matches `MON` and `MONTH`;
- `MON` matches `MONTH` (and vice versa);
- `RR` matches `RRRR`; and
- The punctuation is optional.

So:

```
SELECT TO_DATE( '10AUGUST2016', 'DD-MM-RR'    ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE( '10AUGUST2016', 'DD-MON-RR'   ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE( '10AUGUST2016', 'DD-MONTH-RR' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE( '10AUG2016',    'DD-MM-RR'    ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE( '10AUG2016',    'DD-MON-RR'   ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE( '10AUG2016',    'DD-MONTH-RR' ) FROM DUAL;
```

All generate the date `2016-08-10T00:00:00`.

You can prevent this by using the [`FX` format model](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#sthref469)

> ## FX
>
> Format exact. This modifier specifies exact matching for the character argument and datetime format model of a `TO_DATE` function:
>
> - Punctuation and quoted text in the character argument must exactly match (except for case) the corresponding parts of the format model.
> - The character argument cannot have extra blanks. Without `FX`, Oracle ignores extra blanks.
> - Numeric data in the character argument must have the same number of digits as the corresponding element in the format model. Without `FX`, numbers in the character argument can omit leading zeroes.
>
>   When `FX` is enabled, you can disable this check for leading zeroes by using the `FM` modifier as well.
>
> If any portion of the character argument violates any of these conditions, then Oracle returns an error message.

Then:

```
SELECT TO_DATE( '10-AUGUST-2016', 'FXDD-MM-RR'    ) FROM DUAL;
```

Gives: `ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected` and would only match where an exact pattern match is found (although `RR` will still match `RRRR`).

> I guess implicit conversion is taking place?

Yes, oracle is implicitly using `TO_DATE( '10AUGUST2016', NLS_DATE_FORMAT )` to do the conversion.

If you use:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'FXDD-MM-RR';
```

Then your insert will fail.

Comment: The format substitution is shown [later in the same doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#sthref478) (or [12cR2 version](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Format-Models.htm#GUID-5B755E80-3CB2-4901-BBCF-F0FC764E0BB5), which has an extra bullet about punctuation characters).

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks, I'd scanned through that document and not spotted it. I'm assuming that my brain had melted before I'd reached that penultimate section. Updated now to point at the section you referenced.

Comment: @MT0 I dont think RR can match RRRR even after using `FX`. As I see `select to_date('20-04-2017','fxdd-mm-rr') from dual` fails ORA-01830.