# oracle - convert many date formats to a single formatted date

Tags: oracle, date, format

I want to bring a string which contains a date to a single format date.
EX:

- 13-06-2012   to 13-JUN-12
- 13/06/2012 to 13-JUN-12
- 13-JUN-2012 to
  13-JUN-12
- 13/jun-2012 to 13-JUN-12
- ...

I tried to delete all special characters and after that use a function to transform that string into a single format of date. My function return more exceptions, I don't know why...

The function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION normalize_date (data_in IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN DATE
IS
    tmp_month         VARCHAR2 (3);
    tmp_day           VARCHAR2 (2);
    tmp_year          VARCHAR2 (4);
    TMP_YEAR_NUMBER   NUMBER;
    result            DATE;
BEGIN
    tmp_day := SUBSTR (data_in, 1, 2);
    tmp_year := SUBSTR (data_in, -4);

    --if(REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(data_in,3,2), '[:alpha:]')) then 
    if(SUBSTR(data_in,3,1) in ('a','j','i','f','m','s','o','n','d','A','J','I','F','M','S','O','N','D')) then      
    tmp_month := UPPER(SUBSTR (data_in, 3, 3));
    else
    tmp_month := SUBSTR (data_in, 3, 2);
    end if;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (tmp_year);

    TMP_YEAR_NUMBER := TO_NUMBER (tmp_year);

    IF (tmp_month = 'JAN')
    THEN
        tmp_month := '01';
    END IF;

    IF (tmp_month = 'FEB')
    THEN
        tmp_month := '02';
    END IF;

    IF (tmp_month = 'MAR')
    THEN
        tmp_month := '03';
    END IF;

    IF (tmp_month = 'APR')
    THEN
        tmp_month := '04';
    END IF;

    IF (tmp_month = 'MAY')
    THEN
        tmp_month := '05';
    END IF;

    IF (tmp_month = 'JUN')
    THEN
        tmp_month := '06';
    END IF;

    IF (tmp_month = 'JUL')
    THEN
        tmp_month := '07';
    END IF;

    IF (tmp_month = 'AUG')
    THEN
        tmp_month := '08';
    END IF;

    IF (tmp_month = 'SEP')
    THEN
        tmp_month := '09';
    END IF;

    IF (tmp_month = 'OCT')
    THEN
        tmp_month := '10';
    END IF;

    IF (tmp_month = 'NOV')
    THEN
        tmp_month := '11';
    END IF;

    IF (tmp_month = 'DEC')
    THEN
        tmp_month := '12';
        END IF;

   -- dbms_output.put_line(tmp_day || '~'||tmp_year || '~' ||tmp_month);

    IF (LENGTH (tmp_day || tmp_year || tmp_month) <> 8)
    THEN
        result := TO_DATE ('31122999', 'DDMMYYYY');
        RETURN result;
    END IF;

 --   dbms_output.put_line('before end');
    result:=TO_DATE (tmp_day || tmp_month ||tmp_year , 'DDMMYYYY');
 --   dbms_output.put_line('date result: '|| result);
    RETURN result;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        result := TO_DATE ('3012299', 'DDMMYYYY');
        RETURN result;
        RAISE;
END normalize_date;
```

Usage

```
SELECT customer_no,
       str_data_expirare,
       normalize_date (str_data_expirare_trim) AS data_expirare_buletin
  FROM (SELECT customer_no,
               str_data_expirare,
               REGEXP_REPLACE (str_data_expirare, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '')
                   AS str_data_expirare_trim
          FROM (SELECT Q1.set_act_id_1,
                       Q1.customer_no,
                       NVL (SUBSTR (set_act_id_1,
                                      INSTR (set_act_id_1,
                                             '+',
                                             1,
                                             5)
                                    + 1,
                                    LENGTH (set_act_id_1)),
                            'NULL')
                           AS str_data_expirare
                  FROM STAGE_CORE.IFLEX_CUSTOMERS Q1
                  WHERE Q1.set_act_id_1 IS NOT NULL
                  )
        );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a sound idea of all the possible date formats it might be easier to use brute force:

```
create or replace function clean_date
    ( p_date_str in varchar2)
    return date
is
    l_dt_fmt_nt sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll
        ('DD-MON-YYYY', 'DD-MON-YY', 'DD-MM-YYYY', 'MM-DD-YYYY', 'YYYY-MM-DD'
         , 'DD/MM/YYYY', 'MM/DD/YYYY', 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'DD/MM/YY', 'MM/DD/YY');
    return_value date;
begin
    for idx in l_dt_fmt_nt.first()..l_dt_fmt_nt.last()
    loop
        begin
            return_value := to_date(p_date_str, l_dt_fmt_nt(idx));
            exit;
        exception
             when others then null;
        end;
    end loop;
    if return_value is null then
        raise no_data_found; 
    end if;
    return return_value;
exception
    when no_data_found then
        raise_application_error(-20000, p_date_str|| ' is unknown date format');
end clean_date;
/
```

Be aware that modern versions of Oracle are quite forgiving with date conversion. This function handled dates in formats which aren't in the list, with some interesting consequences:

```
SQL> select  clean_date('20160817') from dual;

CLEAN_DAT
---------
17-AUG-16

SQL> select  clean_date('160817') from dual;

CLEAN_DAT
---------
16-AUG-17

SQL>
```

Which demonstrates the limits of automated data cleansing in the face of lax data integrity rules. The wages of sin  is corrupted data.

---

@AlexPoole raises the matter of using the `'RR'` format. This element of the date mask was introduced as a Y2K kludge. It's rather depressing that we're still discussing it almost two decades into the new Millennium.

Anyway, the issue is this. If we cast this string `'161225'` to a date what century does it have? Well, `'yymmdd'` will give `2016-12-15`. Fair enough, but what about `'991225'`? How likely is that the date we really want is `2099-12-15`? This is where the  `'RR'` format comes into play. Basically it defaults the century: numbers 00-49 default to 20, 50-99 default to 19. This window was determined by the Y2K issue: in 2000 it was more likely that `'98` referred to the recent past than the near future, and similar logic applied to `'02`. Hence the halfway point of 1950. Note this is **a fixed point** not a sliding window. As we move further from the year 2000 the less useful that pivot point becomes. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#i116004).

Anyway, the key point is that 'RRRR' does not play nicely with other date formats: `to_date('501212', 'rrrrmmdd') hurls`ora-01843: not a valid month`. So, use`'RR'`and test for it before using`'YYYY'`. So my revised function (with some tidying up) looks like this:

```
create or replace function clean_date
    ( p_date_str in varchar2)
    return date
is
    l_dt_fmt_nt sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll
        ('DD-MM-RR', 'MM-DD-RR', 'RR-MM-DD', 'RR-DD-MM'
         , 'DD-MM-YYYY', 'MM-DD-YYYY', 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'YYYY-DD-MM');
    return_value date;
begin
    for idx in l_dt_fmt_nt.first()..l_dt_fmt_nt.last()
    loop
        begin
            return_value := to_date(p_date_str, l_dt_fmt_nt(idx));
            exit;
        exception
             when others then null;
        end;
    end loop;
    if return_value is null then
        raise no_data_found; 
    end if;
    return return_value;
exception
    when no_data_found then
        raise_application_error(-20000, p_date_str|| ' is unknown date format');
end clean_date;
/
```

The key point remains: there's a limit to how smart we can make this function when it comes to interpreting dates, so make sure you lead with the best fit. If you think most of your date strings fit day-month-year put that first; you will still get some wrong casts but less that if you lead with year-month-day.

Comment: I guess you could add FXFM to all the formats to control the laxness, but then you need more variations (for different punctuation for a start), and you still have the ambiguity issue between US/European formats, and then there's the date language... Worth a +1 just for the last line *8-) Is there a reason not to use RR for the two-digit-year variations, as long as you check 4-digit first?

Answer (score 2):

The [String-to-Date Conversion Rules](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#sthref478) allow additional formatting rules (without any other modifiers being applied). (Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43758855/1509264)) So:

- `MM` also matches `MON` and `MONTH`;
- `MON` also matches `MONTH` (and vice versa);
- `YY` also matches `YYYY`;
- `RR` also matches `RRRR`; and
- The punctuation is optional.

Which means you can do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION parse_Date_String(
  in_string VARCHAR2
) RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    RETURN TO_DATE( in_string, 'DD-MM-YY' );
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      NULL;
  END;
  BEGIN
    RETURN TO_DATE( in_string, 'MM-DD-YY' );
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      NULL;
  END;
  BEGIN
    RETURN TO_DATE( in_string, 'YY-MM-DD' );
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      NULL;
  END;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```
WITH dates ( value ) AS (
  SELECT '010101' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '02JAN01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '03JANUARY01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '04012001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '05JAN2001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '06JANUARY2001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'JAN0701' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'JANUARY0801' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'JAN0901' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'JANUARY1001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '990111' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '99JAN12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '99JANUARY13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '19990114' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '2001-01-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '2001JAN16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '2001JANUARY17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '20010118' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT value, parse_Date_String( value ) AS dt
FROM   dates;
```

**Output**:

```
VALUE         DT
------------- -------------------
010101        2001-01-01 00:00:00
02JAN01       2001-01-02 00:00:00
03JANUARY01   2001-01-03 00:00:00
04012001      2001-01-04 00:00:00
05JAN2001     2001-01-05 00:00:00
06JANUARY2001 2001-01-06 00:00:00
JAN0701       2001-01-07 00:00:00
JANUARY0801   2001-01-08 00:00:00
JAN092001     2001-01-09 00:00:00
JANUARY102001 2001-01-10 00:00:00
990111        2099-01-11 00:00:00
99JAN12       2099-01-12 00:00:00
99JANUARY13   2099-01-13 00:00:00
19990114      1999-01-14 00:00:00
2001-01-15    2001-01-15 00:00:00
2001JAN16     2001-01-16 00:00:00
2001JANUARY17 2001-01-17 00:00:00
20010118      0118-01-20 00:00:00
```

*(Note: the date formats you are using are ambiguous, as the last example demonstrates. You can swap the order the formats are parsed in the function to get different results but if you have `010203` is it `01-FEB-2003`, `02-JAN-2003`, `03-FEB-2001` or even `01-FEB-0003`?)*

If you want it in the format `DD-MON-YY` (but why `YY` and not `YYYY`?) then just use:

```
TO_CHAR( parse_Date_String( value ), 'DD-MON-YY' )
```