# How to Insert '/' after 2nd and 4th char in varchar column of an Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am new to Oracle and working in Oracle 10g. I have a table `WW_WAGEMAST` and it has a column of type `varchar2(11)` for saving `PF_Join_date`. It has date in both format `ddmmyyyy` and `dd/mm/yyyy`. I want to convert all date in single format dd/mm/yyy. How can I do that ?

For example - current situation:

```
PF_JOIN_DATE
------------
01/04/2018 
02042018 
03042018 
04/04/2018 
05042018
```

I need to change all to a single format like this:

```
PF_JOIN_DATE
---------------
01/04/2018 
02/04/2018 
03/04/2018 
04/04/2018 
05/04/2018
```

How can I do that? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: its bad design using varchar for date use date datatype instead

Comment: *"I want to convert all date in single format dd/mm/yyyy"*  - Why?. Since you are planning to change the records, I would suggest that it's a good opportunity to totally revamp the table definition and change the datatype of `PF_JOIN_DATE` to date. Simply use a function like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43777253/7998591) that returns  date to put it into another column, drop `PF_Join_date` and rename this column to `PF_Join_date`

Comment: Never store DATE values in `varchar` columns. Your current problem is a direct result of that bad design decision.

Answer (score 5):

You can write:

```
update WW_WAGEMAST
set PF_JOIN_DATE = substr(PF_JOIN_DATE, 1, 2) || '/' ||
                   substr(PF_JOIN_DATE, 3, 2) || '/' ||
                   substr(PF_JOIN_DATE, 5, 4)
where PF_JOIN_DATE not like '%/%'
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
CREATE TABLE d061_Table1
    ("PF_JOIN_DATE" varchar2(10))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO d061_Table1 ("PF_JOIN_DATE")
         VALUES ('01/04/2018')
    INTO d061_Table1 ("PF_JOIN_DATE")
         VALUES ('02042018')
    INTO d061_Table1 ("PF_JOIN_DATE")
         VALUES ('03042018')
    INTO d061_Table1 ("PF_JOIN_DATE")
         VALUES ('04/04/2018')
    INTO d061_Table1 ("PF_JOIN_DATE")
         VALUES ('05042018')
SELECT * FROM dual
;

select * from d061_Table1;
update d061_Table1 set PF_JOIN_DATE=
(substr(PF_JOIN_DATE, 1, 2) || '/' ||
          substr(PF_JOIN_DATE, 3, 2) || '/' ||
          substr(PF_JOIN_DATE, 5, 4))
where not regexp_like(PF_JOIN_DATE, '^[0-9]{2,}/{1}[0-9]{2,}/{1}[0-9]{4,}$');

select * from d061_Table1;

output:
01/04/2018
02/04/2018
03/04/2018
04/04/2018
05/04/2018
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind support and efforts. It works so fine.

Comment: @FARHAN  you can give it a green tick now

Answer (score 0):

With regexp.

```
update plv_test_table t
set t.pf_join_date = regexp_replace(t.pf_join_date, '^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})$','\1/\2/\3')
```

Optionally - depending on size of your table it can be faster to update all or only part of rows. Without where clause this query still correct.

```
where t.pf_join_date not like '%/%'
```