# How to reformat multiple different dates in Impala/hive

Tags: sql, hive, impala

In table, there are dates saved in various format. E.g.

```
19/Jun/1965     
30-Jun-1980
29-Mar-1970
Jun-12-1969
```

I want them to all be saved in same format. I was trying case when approach to sort it into sub-sets and solve each individualy

```
select birthdate, 
case 
when birthdate like '%-%' then cast(unix_timestamp(birthdate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy') as timestamp) 
when birthdate like '%/%' then cast(unix_timestamp(birthdate, 'dd/MMM/yyyy') as timestamp) 
end from patientinfo;
```

But this will lead probably into multiple nested case-when queries.

Is there any better approach how to convert all the data into same date format ?

Comment: Probably not.  You probably need to try all formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

You can write your own UDF function that do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776687/oracle-convert-many-date-formats-to-a-single-formatted-date).
You need to loop through all the possible formats and try to validate the data on each format. In case of invalidate, return a message or a value default, like '1000-01-01'.

You can see [here](https://blog.dataiku.com/2013/05/01/a-complete-guide-to-writing-hive-udf) how to build UDF functions.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As F.Lazarescu pointed out, you can do it using 'external' tools as UDF (which may be easier if you are used to them and languages like Java or C++) or you can simply use regular expressions.

Impala provides regexp_extract for this purposes. I made a query which you could use for the dates you stated above.

In case your dates could have other syntax, you should add it to the regular expression possibilities:

```
select date_time,
case
when 
    -- If it starts with a number(day)
    regexp_extract(date_time, '^(\\d+).*?', 1)!='' THEN
    cast(unix_timestamp(
            concat(
            regexp_extract(date_time, '^(\\d+).*?', 1),-- Day
            '/',
            -- Extract and convert the month
            case 
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '([a-zA-Z]+?)', 1)='Jan' then '01'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '([a-zA-Z]+?)', 1)='Feb' then '02'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '([a-zA-Z]+?)', 1)='Mar' then '03'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '([a-zA-Z]+?)', 1)='Apr' then '04'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '([a-zA-Z]+?)', 1)='May' then '05'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '([a-zA-Z]+?)', 1)='Jun' then '06'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '([a-zA-Z]+?)', 1)='Jul' then '07'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '([a-zA-Z]+?)', 1)='Aug' then '08'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '([a-zA-Z]+?)', 1)='Sep' then '09'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '([a-zA-Z]+?)', 1)='Oct' then '10'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '([a-zA-Z]+?)', 1)='Nov' then '11'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '([a-zA-Z]+?)', 1)='Dec' then '12'
            else null 
            end,
            '/',
            regexp_extract(fecha, '(\\d+)$', 1)
            ),
        'dd/MM/yyyy') as timestamp)

WHEN 
        -- If it starts with an String (month)
        regexp_extract(date_time, '^([a-zA-Z]+).*?', 1) !='' then 
        cast(unix_timestamp(
            concat(
            regexp_extract(date_time, '(\\d+)', 1),-- Day
            '/',
            case 
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '^([a-zA-Z]+).*?', 1)='Jan' then '01'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '^([a-zA-Z]+).*?', 1)='Feb' then '02'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '^([a-zA-Z]+).*?', 1)='Mar' then '03'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '^([a-zA-Z]+).*?', 1)='Apr' then '04'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '^([a-zA-Z]+).*?', 1)='May' then '05'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '^([a-zA-Z]+).*?', 1)='Jun' then '06'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '^([a-zA-Z]+).*?', 1)='Jul' then '07'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '^([a-zA-Z]+).*?', 1)='Aug' then '08'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '^([a-zA-Z]+).*?', 1)='Sep' then '09'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '^([a-zA-Z]+).*?', 1)='Oct' then '10'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '^([a-zA-Z]+).*?', 1)='Nov' then '11'
            when 
            regexp_extract(date_time, '^([a-zA-Z]+).*?', 1)='Dec' then '12'
            else null 
            end,
            '/',
            regexp_extract(date_time, '(\\d+)$', 1)),
        'dd/MM/yyyy') as timestamp)
else null 
end as converted_datetime
from mytable;
```

Hope it helps.