# Converting different dates format into single date format

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my application client can provide date in any formats and I have to display given date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format only.The date formats are as-

```
1. dd-mmm-yyyy (Ex- 21-Jan-2019)
2. dd/mm/yyyy (Ex- 02/03/2019)
3. mm/dd/yyyy (Ex- 04/23/2019)
4. dd.mm.yyyy (Ex- 08.02.2019)
5. dd mmmm yyyy (Ex- 13 March 2019)
6. yyyy-mm-dd (Ex- 2019-03-04)
7. mmmm dd, yyyy (Ex- January 23, 2019)
```

Pls suggest how can I use regex for identifying date format and then convert into desired format.

Comment: what is datatype of the column that contains those date's ??

Comment: You can't identify the format. There is no way to know if your second example 02/03/2019 is dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy, you need to supply that information.

Comment: Hii I searched a lot in google but found no result.User can enter date in any format and I have to convert all dates into dd/mm/yyyy format only. Can't we have any alternate for this.

Comment: I am using varchar for holding all dates

Comment: Hi, maybe you can write a function, like in [this page answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776687/oracle-convert-many-date-formats-to-a-single-formatted-date) . In that function you an try to put all the possible formats.

Comment: Why would you use varchar for using dates? There's specific `date` type columns for this - using the proper type makes your life so much easier..

Comment: User is not manually entering data. We have one tool which is extracting date from scanned invoice. And during extraction it can also add some junk characters .Due to this I am using varchar instead of date.

Comment: Are those the only date formats they can enter? Or can they enter 1/2-3/4-//6-*7? If you know all of the possible formats coming in you can handle them. If you don't, then good luck!

Comment: Yes above are the only date formats which I have to convert.

Answer (score 2):

It has already been mentioned that your options (2) and (3) pose an existential problem for solving this problem.  So, this answer ignores that problem.

SQL Server is pretty good about figuring out dates.  So, you can try:

```
select try_convert(date, col)
```

This will return `NULL` values for unknown date formats.  You can also look for particular formats:

```
select coalesce(try_convert(date, col),
                try_convert(date, col, 101),
                try_convert(date, col, 104),
                try_convert(date, col, 120),
                . . .
               )
```

The expressions can be more complicated than `try_convert()` if you need to munge the string value before attempting a conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The example for format 2 in your question is a great example of why this can't be done, i.e. it could be interpreted as either format 2 or 3.

You would need better control over your incoming data, which I think would necessarily require a manual element.

You could perhaps have a rule around which clients are sending dates in which format, if you are pulling some kind of client name/ID into the database, and then you could run the string value through a date conversion function which would be tailored to a specific client or group of clients, but even then, you'd have to trust that this would remain consistent over time.

Comment: Yes Mack I can maintain a list of date formats based on vendor id. But issue is I have long list of vendors and most of the vendors format is unknown and also format is not fixed for specific to vendor. So I have to apply only custom logic to identify dates and then convert the date into dd/mm/yyyy format only.

Comment: Would vendors vary their date formats? If so, I'm not sure it would be possible to do this without manual input for each invoice (even if I were reading '01/02/2019' with my own eyes, unless someone told me the format, I wouldn't know what date that was). If not, perhaps you could set something up where a default fate format is set for each vendor when their first invoice comes in. This would require user input only for new vendors, as well as in some initial startup for current vendors.

Comment: (The way this might work would be that you'd leave new/"unmapped" vendors in some kind of staging table, an then set up some kind of alert to tell users that their input was required.)

Answer (score 0):

When reading those invoices, can't you find the countryCode and instead of setting rules on each vendor, make rules by country?

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(n), GETDATE(), style)
```

Style   Standard

- 100       Default for datetime and smalldatetime
- 110       USA
- 111       JAPAN
- 112       ISO

https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/09/sql-server-date-format-cheatsheet.html