# ORA-01830 while inserting date from one table into another

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have two tables, and I want to insert the records from table one to table two.

Below is my code:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST
(
    CMP, SAP_ID, ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE, ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE, RRH_COUNTCHANGE, RRH_CHANGEDDATE, TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE,
    TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE, RFS_DATE,RFE1_DATE,INFRA_PROVIDER,IP_COLO_SITEID,SITE_NAME,R4GSTATE,MW_INSTALLED,        
    DG_NONDG,EB_NONEB,TOWER_TYPE,VENDOR_CODE, RFCDATE,POLITICAL_STATE_NAME,POLITICAL_STATE_CODE,SITE_DROP_DATE,
    CITY_NAME, NEID,FACILITY_LATITUDE,FACILITY_LONGITUDE,RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE,RJ_JC_NAME, RJ_JC_CODE )

SELECT
CMP,
SAP_ID,
ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE,
ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE,      
RRH_COUNTCHANGE ,       
RRH_CHANGEDDATE  ,      
TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE ,   
TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE ,  
RFS_DATE_BAND ,         
RFE1_DATE_BAND ,       
INFRA_PROVIDER ,        
IP_COLO_SITEID ,        
SITE_NAME ,             
R4GSTATE   ,            
MW_INSTALLED ,          
DG_NONDG      ,         
EB_NONEB       ,        
TOWER_TYPE      ,       
VENDOR_CODE       , 
SITE_RFCDATE,
NULL,
NULL,
SYSDATE ,
CITY_NAME              ,
NEID                   ,
FACILITY_LATITUDE      ,
FACILITY_LONGITUDE     ,
RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE      ,
RJ_JC_NAME             ,
RJ_JC_CODE             

FROM tbl_ipcolo_mast_info;
```

I am getting error:

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Data types of both the tables are mentioned below.

Table1: TBL_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST

```
CMP                           NVARCHAR2(100) 
SAP_ID                        NVARCHAR2(100) 
ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE             NVARCHAR2(100) 
ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE             DATE           
RRH_COUNTCHANGE               NVARCHAR2(100) 
RRH_CHANGEDDATE               DATE           
TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE           NVARCHAR2(100) 
TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE           DATE           
RFS_DATE                      DATE           
RFE1_DATE                     DATE           
INFRA_PROVIDER                NVARCHAR2(100) 
IP_COLO_SITEID                NVARCHAR2(100) 
SITE_NAME                     NVARCHAR2(500) 
R4GSTATE                      NVARCHAR2(100) 
MW_INSTALLED                  NVARCHAR2(100) 
DG_NONDG                      NVARCHAR2(100) 
EB_NONEB                      NVARCHAR2(100) 
TOWER_TYPE                    NVARCHAR2(100) 
VENDOR_CODE                   NVARCHAR2(100) 
RFCDATE                       DATE           
POLITICAL_STATE_NAME          NVARCHAR2(100) 
POLITICAL_STATE_CODE          NVARCHAR2(100) 
SITE_DROP_DATE                DATE           
CITY_NAME                     NVARCHAR2(100) 
NEID                          NVARCHAR2(100) 
FACILITY_LATITUDE             NVARCHAR2(100) 
FACILITY_LONGITUDE            NVARCHAR2(100) 
RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE             NVARCHAR2(100) 
RJ_JC_NAME                    NVARCHAR2(100) 
RJ_JC_CODE                    NVARCHAR2(100) 
COMPANY_CODE                  NVARCHAR2(100)
```

Table2: tbl_ipcolo_mast_info

```
CMP                          NVARCHAR2(100)  
SAP_ID                       NVARCHAR2(50)   
ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE            NVARCHAR2(20)   
ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE            NVARCHAR2(100)  
RRH_COUNTCHANGE              NVARCHAR2(50)   
RRH_CHANGEDDATE              NVARCHAR2(20)   
TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE          NVARCHAR2(50)   
TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE          NVARCHAR2(100)  
CREATED_BY                   NVARCHAR2(55)   
CREATED_DATE                 DATE            
UMS_GRP_BY_ID                NUMBER          
UMS_GRP_BY_NAME              NVARCHAR2(55)   
UMS_GRP_TO_ID                NUMBER          
UMS_GRP_TO_NAME              NVARCHAR2(55)   
CMM_STATUS                   CHAR(1)         
FCA_STATUS                   CHAR(1)         
LAST_UPDATED_BY              NVARCHAR2(55)   
LAST_UPDATED_DATE            DATE            
RFS_DATE_BAND                NVARCHAR2(100)  
RFE1_DATE_BAND               NVARCHAR2(100)  
SF_SITERRHDATE               NVARCHAR2(100)  
SF_RRHCOUNT                  NVARCHAR2(100)  
INFRA_PROVIDER               NVARCHAR2(250)  
IP_COLO_SITEID               NVARCHAR2(200)  
SITE_NAME                    NVARCHAR2(500)  
R4GSTATE                     NVARCHAR2(100)  
MW_INSTALLED                 NVARCHAR2(100)  
DG_NONDG                     NVARCHAR2(50)   
EB_NONEB                     NVARCHAR2(20)   
TOWER_TYPE                   NVARCHAR2(100)  
SITE_ADDRESS                 NVARCHAR2(1000) 
VENDOR_CODE                  NVARCHAR2(100)  
SITE_RFCDATE                 NVARCHAR2(100)  
CITY_NAME                    NVARCHAR2(100)  
NEID                         NVARCHAR2(55)   
FACILITY_LATITUDE            NVARCHAR2(100)  
FACILITY_LONGITUDE           NVARCHAR2(100)  
RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE            NVARCHAR2(100)  
RJ_JC_NAME                   NVARCHAR2(100)  
RJ_JC_CODE                   NVARCHAR2(100)  
COMPANY_CODE                 VARCHAR2(55)
```

Please suggest what is wrong here.

[image: IMG]

Comment: We don't know anything about your tables or data. But the error means that you are trying to implicitly convert a string value in the source table to a date value in the target table. Either the data types in the two tables are different, in which case you should do explicit conversion and supply the right format model (though you shouldn't have dates as strings in the first place of course), or you have misaligned the column in the source and target table column lists, which doesn't appear to be the case. Are `rfs_date_band` and `rfe1_date_band` actually dates? Those look most suspicious...

Comment: @AlexPoole: sir the datatype is the issue i guess then. I have updated the datatypes information of both the table. Please have a look and let me know. YES THEY are dates column, earlier it was wrongly datatyped with nvarchar.. now I am aligning it properly with proper datatypes

Comment: @AlexPoole: I have updated the question in what format I have the data. Mostly it would be `dd-MM-yyyy` format. So pls suggest how can I move ahead with this

Comment: Try to insert data column by column, so you can check in which column is the problem.

Comment: @hakobot: the issue is in date columns.. but how to set it proper so that it gets inserted is what I want to resolve

Comment: @AlexPoole: is this ok to try `SELECT TO_DATE(ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
FROM tbl_ipcolo_mast_info;` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source data has date values stored as strings, in `nvarchar2(100)` columns for some reason. Oracle is trying to implicitly convert the values using your session's NLS settings, and is not able to - hence the error you are seeing.

You should explicitly convert the strings to dates, using the right format model for the data stored in each column:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST
(
...)
SELECT
CMP,
SAP_ID,
ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE,
to_date(ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE, 'FXDD-MM-YYYY'),     
...
```

etc. But it's more complicated than that, as your image shows an `ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE` of `'-'`, which presumably is supposed to represent no value (so should probably be null really?). That can't be converted to a date, so you could use a case expression to avoid it:

```
...
ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE,
case when ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE != '-' then to_date(ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE, 'FXDD-MM-YYYY') end,     
...
```

Of course, that assumes that is the only nonconvertible value in that column. As it's a string column it could have anything - which is a major reason to use proper data types, as you are now trying to do.

If you are using Oracle 12cR2 or later you could set all nonconvertible values to null by default:

```
...
ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE,
to_date(ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE default null on conversion error, 'FXDD-MM-YYYY'),     
...
```

You then wouldn't need to specify the dash to be ignored, or any other non-date-like values in that column. But it will also ignore things you might think should be dates but which are in a different format. I've included the FX modifier in the format mask so it doesn't convert two-digit year values incorrectly, but this just means they will now be ignored, and set to null in the target table too.

You also said "Mostly it would be dd-MM-yyyy format"; hopefully that means that different source columns are consistently in different formats, and you just need a different model for each column. If one column can have values in multiple formats then you might want to think about cleaning those up before you start. There are ways to try several format models until one converts OK, but that approach isn't ideal.

---

From further discussions in chat, it emerged that some values are DD-Mon-RR, with a mixture in the same column. I pointed to [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43777253/266304) as an example of how to convert with one of several formats; but as anything that can't be converted needs to be ignored here, tweaked it to:

```
create or replace function clean_date
    ( p_date_str in varchar2)
    return date
is
    l_dt_fmt_nt sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll
        ('DD-Mon-RR', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
    return_value date;
begin
    for idx in l_dt_fmt_nt.first()..l_dt_fmt_nt.last()
    loop
        begin
            return_value := to_date(p_date_str, l_dt_fmt_nt(idx));
            exit;
        exception
             when others then null;
        end;
    end loop;
    return return_value;
end clean_date;
/
```

... to be called instead of `to_date()`, i.e. as `clean_date(ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE)`, and without the need for the case expression wrapper. (I also stressed that the data should be thoroughly investigated as there could be values in other date formats that could be salvaged, which this incarnation would set to null.)

Comment: so should I use same like this only `'FXDD-MM-YYYY` ??

Comment: If the string values in the source column are in that format then yes. The values you showed in your image are like that. If some of the columns have differently-formatted string values then they will need a different model to convert them.

Comment: getting `Error at Command Line : 4 Column : 12
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma
00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"` here is code `INSERT INTO TBL_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST
(
    CMP, SAP_ID, ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE,
    TO_DATE(ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE, 'FXDD-MM-YYYY'), 
    RRH_COUNTCHANGE, 
    TO_DATE(RRH_CHANGEDDATE, 'FXDD-MM-YYYY'),....`

Comment: The `to_date()` function calls go in the `SELECT` part, not the column list for the `INSERT INTO (...)` part. (You also seem to have ignored the bits about handling the `'-'` value shown in your image, but that's not what's causing the ORA-00917...)

Comment: oh yeah, resolved that but now getting error as `ORA-01862: the numeric value does not match the length of the format item`

Comment: Which means you have values that are not DD-MM-YYYY format. That may still just be that dash character if you still haven't excluded it. But there could be anything in your tables...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199301/discussion-between-b-n-and-alex-poole).