# Oracle SQL: Extracting the week of the year from date gives random results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been using the following statement to get the week of the year from a date:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(tbl.col,'YYYY/MM/DD'),'IW') AS week
```

Now I'm receiving strange results and I can't seem to figure this out. For the following dates I receive the week 24:

> 19-Jun-17 || 23-Jun-17 || 24-Jun-17 || 25-Jun-17 || 29-Jun-17 || 30-Jun-17

For these, I receive 25:

> 20-Jun-17 || 21-Jun-17 || 22-Jun-17 || 26-Jun-17 || 27-Jun-17 || 28-Jun-17

...and this continues. I'm a bit worried now that all my queries show incorrect data. The only reason I have noticed it only now is because there are no results for weeks 26, 27, 30, 31 and 32 which is not the case in any of my other queries.

Any suggestions or pointers towards possible errors are appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the datatype of the tbl.col?

Comment: The datatype is "date"

Comment: Why convert date to date? Just `TO_CHAR(tbl.col,'IW') AS week`

Comment: to add to what Serg said, **NEVER** to_date something that is already a date. If you do, you force an implicit conversion to take place, along the lines of: `to_date(to_char(your_date_col, '<nls_date_format parameter value>'), '<your format mask>')`. In your case, it looks like your nls_date_format parameter is not the same as the format mask you are putting in, and you are getting odd results. If you're wanting to remove the time element from the date, use `trunc(your_date_column)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this could actually be the cause. Looking at other queries, I somehow added the to_date function for this one.

Comment: @Boneist What you mentioned was the cause, thank you for spotting it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[TL;DR]** Just use: `TO_CHAR( tbl.col, 'IW' )`

You have multiple issues:

1. > The datatype is "date"

   You are calling `TO_DATE( string, format_model )` with a `DATE` (not a `VARCHAR2`) which causes Oracle to do an implicit conversion of the `DATE` to a `VARCHAR2` using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model just so you can convert it back to a `DATE`. So, you are effectively doing:

   ```
   TO_CHAR(
     TO_DATE(
       TO_CHAR(
         tbl.col,
         ( SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
       ),
       'YYYY/MM/DD'
     ),
     'IW'
   )
   ```

   **Do not do this**, just use:

   ```
   TO_CHAR( tbl.col, 'IW' )
   ```

   If you do that then the following issues are irrelevant.
2. As RealCheeseLord points out, the position of year and day in your format model is reversed; and
3. You are using `YYYY` for the year format model so all the years are going to be in the 1st Century AD.

   **Example**:

   ```
   SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE( '19-Jun-17', 'YYYY/MM/DD' ), 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) AS dt
   FROM   DUAL
   ```

   **Output**:

   ```
   DT
   ----------
   0019-06-17
   ```

   If you aren't going to fix the implicit string conversion then you would probably want either:

   ```
   TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(tbl.col,'DD-MON-YY'),'IW') AS week
   ```

   or (depending on whether you want the year 99 to be 1999 or 2099):

   ```
   TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(tbl.col,'DD-MON-RR'),'IW') AS week
   ```
4. You are using the `MM` format model for `MON` formatted data - this is not necessarily an issue as [`MM` also matches `MON` and `MONTH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43758855/1509264) but you should probably use the correct model.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong order of year and day. those weeks are correct for example 17.06.2020 is week 25, 17.06.2023 is week 24 and so on.

Try: `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(tbl.col,'DD-MON-YY'),'IW') AS week`

or something

[examples at bottom of page](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Comment: I have not considered this to be an issue before, thanks! I'm trying this out right now, will let you know if this resolves it