# Oracle SQL: How to check if a calendar week is in between two calendar weeks

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to check if a `calendar week` is in between two calendar weeks using `PL/SQL`.

Let's say the calendar week I want to check is `26`. When I check if this is `between 24 and 27`, then it should return `true`.

This part is easy I can use `BETWEEN X AND Y` and this solves the problem.

However if the calendar week I want to check is `52` and If I want to check if this is `between 50 and 3`, this should return `true`. As you realized, using `BETWEEN X AND Y` won't give the right result here.

Well, I can check which calendar week is greater, and I can do the comparisons based on that but this doesn't sound like an elegant solution to me. What would you suggest in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't compare only 2 week number, because any week number is alway between 2 another week !

You need precise the YEAR and have a fixed format with leading zero :

example :

```
'2017-W52' is     between '2017-W50' and '2018-W03'

'2018-W52' is not between '2017-W50' and '2018-W03'
```

String containing `date` can be compare using [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) format

Comment: This is the better answer in my opinion.

Comment: Let's say I know the date, how can I turn it into this format?

Comment: to_char(columnDate,'yyyy-"W"iw')

Comment: If you can also tell me how to turn just week number and year into this format, I can go home.

Comment: Using to_char() function you can format your date to the appropriate format YYYY-WW using pattern 'yyyy-iw'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45628900/oracle-sql-extracting-the-week-of-the-year-from-date-gives-random-results

Comment: No, I meant, In some cases I don't have the date, I have just information about year and week number.

Comment: You can simply concat Year and week number using lpad  to add trailling zero : myYear || lpad(myWeek,'0',2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use logic like this:

```
where (x <= y and v_week >= x and v_week <= y) or
      (x > y and (v_week <= x or v_week >= y))
```

You can almost write this as:

```
where (x <= y and v_week between x and y) or
      (x > y and v_week not between x and y)
```

However, this is incorrect for the second case when `v_week in (x, y)`.